# Load Select2 4.0 options with PHP script

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working with CodeIgniter and I want to make a Select2, but that doesn't work.
My php script returns a JSON but nothing is displaying.

Does anyone have an example or something to help me out?

Comment: plz submit your code for better understanding

Comment: I pack it and send you the code

Comment: There's a format in which select2 expects the JSON to be. Post your code, and we'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code for the Controller's method :

```
public function getPrestationsAjax(){
    echo json_encode($this->prestation->getPrestations());
}
```

getPrestations() gets an array of resultats from  de database.

In the ajax Select2, the URL is that one:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Accueil/getPrestationsAjax"
```

Accueil is my controller and getPrestationsAjax.

Is the URL good ?

Thanks